# Context leak detected, msgtracer returned -1 (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift-playground

Running Xcode 8.2 on a Swift Playground. It's also making Xcode not respond. This is the error I'm getting.

```
Context leak detected, msgtracer returned -1
```

I've traced the problem to these lines of code

```
while (true){
    let rotate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 1)
    crank.run(rotate)
    }
```

When I comment out the while loop and leave just the inside it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rewriting it completely and using SKAction.repeatForever to run an SKAction (to rotate) and that terminated only if the condition was false.

```
crank.run(
        SKAction.repeatForever (
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1),
                SKAction.run({

                    let angle = atan2(self.point.y - crank.position.y , self.point.x - crank.position.x)
                    let rotate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 0.25)
                    crank.run(rotate)
                    if(!(crank.frame.contains(self.point))) {
                        self.removeAction(forKey: "New Thread")
                    }
                })
                ])
        ),
        withKey: "New Thread"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while (true){` part will make that loop execute forever and your code probably will not proceed beyond that point. If you want an action to repeat forever there is an SKAction method for that - take a look at `repeat`.

If you remove the `while (true){` condition and instead use a `repeat` action, I believe your code should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Fahim is 100% correct, by the code posted you are stuck in an endless loop. So the question for you is how to get out of it?

The question for you is - how to make this loop do what you need. I'll guess that you want to change the condition to something like *while (someVar == true)* and put in a condition **inside** your loop to change *someVar* to false. But only you know what that condition is. The syntax would be:

```
let someVar = true
while (someVar == true){
    let rotate = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2), duration: 1)
    crank.run(rotate)
    if someCondition == isMet {   // THIS IS FOR YOU TO DECIDE!
        someVar = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This does get rid of the error, but the problem now is if I set someVar false, how would I recheck after the while loop ends to see if the condition switched back to true? To be more specific, I am trying to check if the mouse pointer is within a rect, and if it is, I want the rect to rotate towards the mouse pointer's position. But in this code, after I take my mouse pointer off the rect, how would I check if I put the mouse pointer back on the rect?

Comment: Oh. You need to do more. (Nothing in your question suggested this. Still, I find it to be a good question.) Two thoughts: (1) First, maybe you are over thinking something. If you care to rotate, consider other apps. Do *they* check the mouse pointer position? Or do they make you think in those terms somehow? I don't know, there are many ways to do this. (2) Look into something every view should have (I work mainly with UIView, not NSView) - **hitTest()**. I *believe* either UIKit or Cocoa views have it natively - but each has a CALayer that *does*. It tracks whether that view is involved.

Comment: Now if you need more - the "life cycle" of a UIButton - look into **.touchDown**, **.touchUpInside**, and **.touchUpOutside**. But at this point I have to say your question is ambiguous or vague. What exactly are you trying to do with the rectangle? (Is it a view? iOS? macOS?)

Comment: Sorry for my terrible explainations.. The rectangle is actually a frame of an SKSpriteNode. I'm trying to rotate the rect (SKSpriteNode) towards the mouse pointer only if the mouse is touching the rect. Its supposed to act like I'm cranking a music box.

Answer (score 0):

I think the existing answers are missing the point here. You have two "threads" you are dealing with: the active thread running the routine (which will keep pumping new rotate actions onto the actions list for the node as fast as it can) and the action processing thread (which is really not a "thread" per se but can be imagined as one for the purpose of this question) which is where the rotate actions are actually executed.

Essentially, in a given timeslice, the "main" execution thread might pump 100k "rotate" actions onto your node's action list, and the SpriteKit engine will process all of them at the same time as efficiently as it can (I believe by removing duplicate actions but I'm not positive on that).

The effect is that you are doing a lot more work than you have to, and burning CPU in both your spin loop and in the SKAction processing code trying to recover from the millions of actions added to the node every time it comes up to process.

Replace it with a repeat action, as Fahim suggested, and you'll be good. Then you just need a trigger of some sort to stop the action (give it a name to end just the one action, or stop all actions on this node when the trigger fires).

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem using more singletong. For example SKView() inside  the loop in singletong.